# Row Id is not created in a table for a 1: 1 realtionship in EF CodeFirst

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am having a class which is having instance of other class in itself as a property

```
Class A
```

{

```
 Public B PropB {get;set;}
```

}

When I see the Data Model of the class I see B as a navigation property in the A entity's data model but when I see the table for A, **then I am unable to see the column with this name PropB_RowID as Entity framework is supposed to do that**. So, can anybody tell me the actual or possible reasons for this

Answer (score 0):

In a `one-to-one` relationship, EF will set the `PK` of the first entity to be the `PK` of the second entity, there is no `FK` column. You can have navigation properties in both entity A and B, and you will be able to access either one.